# Filtering Date format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data frame looks like -

```
date                           value
2018-04-01 19:50:00.013         29
2018-04-01 19:55:00.012         19
2018-04-01 20:00:00.019         20
2018-04-01 20:05:00.021         43
2018-04-01 20:10:00.005         50
2018-04-01 20:15:00.019         42
2018-04-01 20:20:00.023         65
2018-04-01 20:25:00.013         43
2018-04-01 20:30:00.003         29
2018-04-01 20:35:00.008         49
....
...
2020-04-10 05:45:00.018        639
2020-04-10 05:50:00.008        633
2020-04-10 05:55:00.021        629
2020-04-10 06:00:00.008        619
2020-04-10 06:05:00.011        610
```

I have almost two years data is present and time interval of this data set is 5mins. I want to pickup only data which is present from 6am to 8pm for this 2 years period. My final data frame looks like -

```
date                           value
2018-04-01 19:50:00.013         29
2018-04-01 19:55:00.012         19
2018-04-01 20:00:00.019         20
2020-04-10 06:00:00.008        619
2020-04-10 06:05:00.011        610
```

I have done so far -

pick up min and max date -

```
max(df['date'])
max(df['date'])

mask1 = df['date'] >= '2018-04-01 06:00:00'
mask2 = df['date'] <= '2020-04-10 20:00:00'
df = df[mask1 & mask2]
df.head()
```

But its not working

Comment: Do you have `str`s inside `'date'` column or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) working with `DatetimeIndex`, so convert `Date` to index:

```
df = df.set_index('date').between_time('06:00','20:00')
print (df)
                         value
date                          
2018-04-01 19:50:00.013     29
2018-04-01 19:55:00.012     19
2020-04-10 06:00:00.008    619
2020-04-10 06:05:00.011    610
```

Comment: When I do the below command it's give me the error ..max(df['date'])...KeyError: 'date'

Comment: @NikitaAgarwal - yes, because `Date` is index. So use `df.index.max()` for maximmal value

Comment: Can I do it as a normal column name?

Comment: @NikitaAgarwal - It depends what need. Obviously `df.index` is same like `df['Date']`. But if need column `Date` then use `df = df.set_index('date').between_time('06:00','20:00').reset_index()` then get `Date` column

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter based on time separately as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(['2018-04-01 19:50:00.013', '2018-04-01 20:00:00.019',
'2018-04-01 20:05:00.021'], columns=['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['time'] = [datetime.datetime.time(d) for d in df['date']] 
df[df['time'] < datetime.time(20)]
```